# calculadora de javascript, el resultado me sale nan

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una calculadora de Javascript y resulta que cuando le doy a clic en `=` para ver el resultado me aparece `NAN`, es decir que no es numero creo, pro ya lo cambié en `suma[i]=parseInt(numero)`, para pasarlo a número, alguien que me pueda ayudar, porque ya no se como solucionarlo.

```js
//Declaramos variables
numero=0;
suma=new Array();
i=0;
total=0;
caso=0;
j=0;

function salidauno() {
  numero = numero + document.getElementById("uno").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("salidatotal").value = numero;
}

function salidados() {
  numero = numero + document.getElementById("dos").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("salidatotal").value = numero;
}

function salidatres() {
  numero = numero + document.getElementById("tres").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("salidatotal").value = numero;
}
    
function salida() {
  document.getElementById("salidatotal").value = "";
  suma[i]=parseInt(numero);
  numero=0;
  i++
  total=suma[0];
}

function sumaokok() {
  caso=1;
}

function resta() {
  caso=2;
}

function multiplicacion() {
  caso=3;
}

function division() {
  caso=4;
}

function operacion() {
  if(caso==1) {
    total=total+suma[j+1];
  } else if(caso==2) {
    total=total-suma[j+1];
  } else if(caso==3) {
    total=total*suma[j+1];
  } else if(caso==4) {
    total=total/suma[j+1];
  }
  j++;
}

function resultado() {
  document.getElementById("salidatotal").value = total;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="salidatotal" ></input>
<button id="uno" onclick="salidauno()">1</button>
<button id="dos" onclick="salidados()">2</button>
<button id="tres" onclick="salidatres()">3</button>
<button id="sumaok" onclick="salida();sumaokok();operacion()">+</button>
<button id="resta" onclick="salida();resta();operacion()">-</button>
<button id="multiplicacion" onclick="salida();multiplicacion();operacion()">*</button>
<button id="division" onclick="salida();operacion()">/</button>
<button id="resultadook" onclick="resultado()">=</button>
```

Comment: Hacer esas cosas que haces en `salidauno()` son completamente innecesarias, (me refiero al innerHTML y al .value). Nada más se debe de declarar `numero = 1`. Así en todas la salidas. Intenta eso, y me dices como te fue. Saludos.

Comment: si, tienes razon , pero eso no me influye en  que el resultado me salga nan, no entiendo porque

Comment: Checkea la respuesta de @RobertoLeOr

Answer (score 0):

Tu error esta en función `operacion` tienes `j` que al inicio es cero; ahora bien en la primer (y siguiente) interacción(es) le sumas uno para obtener el indice del array que usaras.

Es decir cuando `i=0` `j` también es cero; es ese mismo acto al pulsar cualquier operaciones quieres acceder  a `suma[j+1];` cuando el arreglo `suma` solo tiene un elemento quieres acceder a `suma[1]` cuando solo existe `suma[0]` y asi sucesivamente.

Cuestión realices algunos ajustes/correcciones en base al flujo del sistema que tienes planeado; en este momento (lo que detecte) es que en base a los momentos que quieres obtener un indice del arreglo, estes haciendo referencia a uno existente; lo que pasa es que obtienes `undefined` por eso el `NaN` que te devuelve.